# Dynamically add annotation to an existing class

Tags: java

I have the following class

```
public class Person {
   ...
}
```

I would like to create another class that would look like this.

```
@SomeAnnotation
public class Person {
   ...
}
```

Via a simple method like so.

```
public static Class addAnnotation(Class originalType, Class<? extends Annotation> annotation) {
   // what goes here?
}
```

Is there an easy way to do this via ASM for example? What dependencies would I need. I have tried to Google this however the examples I have found are either incomplete or are doing something else. Other frameworks such as javassist would be just as good.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [javassist](http://www.csg.is.titech.ac.jp/%7Echiba/javassist/) project for that.

With javassist it will be look something like that:

```
ClassFile cf = ... ;
ConstPool cp = cf.getConstPool();
AnnotationsAttribute attr = new AnnotationsAttribute(cp, AnnotationsAttribute.visibleTag);

Annotation a = new Annotation("Author", cp);
a.addMemberValue("name", new StringMemberValue("Chiba", cp));
attr.setAnnotation(a);
cf.addAttribute(attr);
cf.setVersionToJava5();
```

Hope it helps.
Alexey