# Android: denote that all fields of an interface are @Nullable

Tags: java, android, null, retrofit, nullable

I am loading data from a REST API using Retrofit.

I know that this API sometimes return partial results: some fields are sometimes missing.

To make sure I handle these cases properly, I am currently annotating the fields with `@Nullable` in the interface that defines the API:

```
class RedactedForecast implements Serializable {
    @Nullable String date;
    @Nullable String time;
    @Nullable String overview_title;
    @Nullable String overview;
    @Nullable String forecast_title;
    @Nullable String forecast;
}
```

However adding this annotation everywhere is not convenient since the result objects are complex.

**Is there a way to say that all the fields from a class can potentially be null? Is there a better way to handle this?**

Comment: Doubt it, since primitives for example cannot be nullable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However adding this annotation everywhere is not convenient since the result objects are complex.

Decouple the structure and map data to partial objects for the easier development.

Unfortunately there is no easy way to annotate the whole class which applies a certain annotation to all its fields.

If you still rely on this solution, I suggest you to take a look on the library [Javassist](http://jboss-javassist.github.io/javassist/), which provides a solution for this. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944896/dynamically-add-annotation-to-an-existing-class) is the example of usage as answer of actually existing question.

Answer (score 0):

In your response when you receive the data then store that in array list like:

ArrayList vList=response.body();

Here, all the data then stored in vList object.

Now in this activity make a function like:

public ArrayList getVideosPlz() {

```
    ArrayList<RedactedForecast> videos = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i <vList.size() ; i++) {
            RedactedForecast users1=new RedactedForecast();
            String id=vList.get(i).getId();
            if(id!=null)
            {
            users1.setId(id);
            }
            videos.add(users1);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Sorry Server Down. Try again!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    return videos;
}
```

Here in the above function you can see that only when the data !=null, the data will set into new array called videos and at the end when all data received then this "videos" object return and receive in the retrofit onResponse as:

ArrayList receiveData=getVideosplz();

Finally, you can pass this receiveData into your recyclerview etc.

Hope it Helps. Thanks!!!

Comment: The idea of `@Nullable` is to use static analysis to point out where in your code an NPE could happen to be sure you handle it correctly. Usually you want to do something specific depending on what field is missing.

Answer (score 0):

A much better solution is to use Kotlin, which makes it much easier to handle `null`s safely.